# Two way array binding in AngularJS gets an empty set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-bindings

I'm having some troubles to assing an array bound to my component.

My parent template:

```
<custom-component c-data-source="vm.dataSource"></custom-component>
```

vm.dataSource is an array of string.

My custom component:

```
.component('customComponent', {
  bindings: {
    cDataSource: '='
  },
  controller: function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = [];
    vm.$onInit = onInit;

    function onInit() {
      vm.data = vm.cDataSource;
      console.log(vm);
    }
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  template: `
     {{ vm.cDataSource | json }}
     {{ vm.data | json }}
  `
}
```

My console output

```
controller {cDataSource: Array(0), ...}
> cDataSource: (4) ['lorem', ...]
```

And my rendered child template:

```
['lorem', ...]
[]
```

It seems like when I'm trying to assign vm.cDataSource to vm.data the set is empty, but when it prints out **vm** in the console, it's empty in the collapsed view but if I expand it, it shows the elements (4 in this case). Also, when I print in the template, the direct bound variable (vm.cDataSource) has elements but the local one (vm.data) does not.

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.0-rc.2.

Comment: It sounds like a scope and by reference issue that is easily fixed.  If you change the assignment of `vm.data` to `vm.data = angular.copy(vm.cDataSource);` you'll likely fix the issue.  This will create a new reference with a copy of the data in `vm.cDataSource`

Comment: It did not solve it but you gave me an idea of what could be the issue. I solved by avoiding the component rendering up to the array has been populated in the parent controller.

Comment: Glad I helped get the gears moving!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change

`<custom-component c-data-source="vm.dataSource"></custom-component>` 
**To** 
`<custom-component c-data-source="dataSource"></custom-component>`

below is my complete code for it :

```
    import angular from 'angular';
      var myMod = angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.DataSource=[1,3,4,5,6,7];
    });`

    myMod.component('customComponent', {
      bindings: {
        cDataSource: '='
      },
      controller: function () {
        var vm = this;
        vm.data = [];
        vm.$onInit = onInit;

        function onInit() {
          vm.data  = vm.cDataSource;
          vm.cDataSource = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
          console.log(vm); 
        }
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      template:`
         {{ vm.cDataSource | json }} 

         {{ vm.data | json }}
      `
    });
```